# Magento doesn't call observer class

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm using the config file below. However when I save a product, the observer class is never called.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <PcTp_Stock>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </PcTp_Stock>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <stock>
            <class>PcTp_Stock_Block</class>
        </stock>
    </blocks>
    <models>
        <stock>
            <class>PcTp_Stock_Model</class>
        </stock>
    </models>

</global>
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <stock>
                <file>stock.xml</file>
            </stock>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <pctp_stock_product_catalog_data_inventory>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>stock/observer</class>
                    <method>saveProductTabData</method>
                </pctp_stock_product_catalog_data_inventory>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

The observer class (Pc_Tp_Stock_Model_Observer) is saved to app/code/local/PcTp/Stock/Model/Observer.php

How do I get this to work?

```
<?php

class Pc_Tp_Stock_Model_Observer
```

Comment: Try catalog_product_prepare_save instead.  Looking at the 1.7 cheat sheet, i cant see that event https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/

Answer (score 0):

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <PcTp_Stock>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </PcTp_Stock>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <PcTp_Stock>
            <class>PcTp_Stock_Model</class>
        </PcTp_Stock>
    </models>
</global>
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <pctp_stock_save_after>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>PcTp_Stock/observer</class>
                    <method>catalogProductSaveAfter</method>
                </pctp_stock_save_after>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

app\code...\PcTp\Stock\Model\Observer.php

```
<?php

class PcTp_Stock_Model_Observer {

    public function catalogProductSaveAfter($observer) {
        die('observer launched');
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your naming architecture looks a bit off where you declare the observer/class. Try changing it to this;

```
<observers>
            <PcTp_Stock_Model_Observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>PcTp_Stock_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>saveProductTabData</method>
            </PcTp_Stock_Model_Observer>
</observers>
```

And then in your Model/Observer.php file;

```
class PcTp_Stock_Model_Observer {

    public function saveProductTabData() {

        // Do something

    }

}
```

Also make sure that event is available in 1.7.  I use this site for a quick reference guide for 1.7 https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/ , it might be worth trying catalog_product_prepare_save instead.

Best

Tom